# How do I store SQL result in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

..so that I can show specific lines of queryresult in _Layout file. **The result is ordered randomly**. *Want only one Databaserequest per pagerequest*.

In _Layout.cshtml, (I want these two methods to show the same):

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("RegularAdV2", "AdV2", new { type = "panoramaxl", skip = 0 });}

@{ Html.RenderAction("RegularAdV2", "AdV2", new { type = "panoramaxl", skip = 0 });}
```

Childaction:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
         public PartialViewResult RegularAdV2(string type,int skip)
         {


             AdViewModel ad = null;
             if ("mobile".Equals(type))
             {
                 if (UserAgentHelper.CheckUserAgent((string)Request.UserAgent, Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice))
                 {
                     ad = repository.MyAds(type, 3, true).Select(x => new AdViewModel { Script = x.AdExtra, ClickUrl = x.AdClickUrl, Place = x.PlacementName, Src = x.AdPath, Title = x.AdTitle }).Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();

                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 if (!UserAgentHelper.CheckUserAgent((string)Request.UserAgent, Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice))
                 {
                    ad = repository.MyAds(type, 3, false).Select(x => new AdViewModel { Script = x.AdExtra, ClickUrl = x.AdClickUrl, Place = x.PlacementName, Src = x.AdPath, Title = x.AdTitle }).Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();

                 }
             }

                 return PartialView(ad);


         }
```

The partial view:

```
@model Jaff.WebUI.Models.AdViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Script))
    {
        <p class="ad-presentation">Annons</p>
        <a href="@Model.ClickUrl" target="_blank"><img alt="annons" class="ad-image" src="//ads.-------.se/AdFiles/img/@Model.Src"></a>
    }
    else
    {
        <p class="ad-presentation">Annons</p>
        <div class="script-box">@Html.Raw(Model.Script)</div>
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
namespace Jaff.WebUI.Models
{
    public class AdViewModel
    {
        public string Src { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ClickUrl { get; set; }
        public string Script { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Asp.net webforms this is easy. I could put placeholders in masterpage and fetch data in it's codebehind...But how do i do in MVC? Is TempData the only alternative?

Comment: You need to explain a little better I think. All the stuff is stored in your view model, why would you want to add it to TempData as well?

Comment: How come the two RenderAction methods doesnt show the same?

Comment: Seems like every RenderAction makes a new databaserequest. I want to use same data for all Renderactions/Childactions since the database-result is ordered radomly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use Session variable to store your sql result, then reuse it later.
For example: Session["SQLQueryData"] = result